# jQuery remove radio button/input choice if user changes dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

[Here is my page](http://sokiusvente2016.org/gala-tickets/testing/). When the user selects a choice from the purchase dropdown menu, either some radio buttons or meal option dropdown menu will appear. I've run into an issue that if the user checks a radio button, but decides to change his purchase option (by going to the purchase dropdown and changing it), then selecting from the meal option dropdown and adding the product to the cart, the radio button option will still be checked and appear on the cart page.

What I am trying to accomplish is if they user flips between purchase choices, then their radio button/input choices will be reset every time.

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //show meal options depending on user choice
        $('form').on('change', '#purchase', function(){
            // Reset required fields and hide fields
            $('select, input').prop('required', false);
            $('#table-meals, .product-addon-please-choose-your-meal').hide();

      if($(this).val()=="Individual") {
        $('.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal').show();
        $("#table-meals").not(".product-addon-please-choose-your-meal").hide();
        $('input').prop('required',true);
        $('#table-meals select').val("Select an Option...");
      }

      if($(this).val()=="Table of 10") {
        $(".product-addon-please-choose-your-meal").not("#table-meals").hide();
        $('#table-meals').show();
        $('select').prop('required',true);
      }
  });
});
```

The first `if` statement accomplishes just that, though it's not perfect; if they user chooses a meal option, then chooses a different purchase option and goes back again, the meal option input field will be blank instead of reading *Select an Option*.

Any idea on how I can get the meal option input field (I plan on having a few) reset whenever a different purchase option is selected?

Comment: Your `$("#table-meals").not(".product-addon-please-choose-your-meal")` says "select the single element table-meals but not if it has the class...Is that your desire?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Sorry, I don't understand your question. That line is using the `.hide()` function to hide the other choice. I am trying to reset/uncheck/default the choice every time the purchase dropdown option is changed.

Comment: Does the element identified by the id "table-meals" have that class of "product-addon-please-choose-your-meal"?  If not, hide it.  That is another way of saying what you have, it just seems odd to have it that way especially as it was just hidden before the conditional...I guess I would have to see your layout just to see if it maks sense really.

Comment: Never mind, that is a useless question and code since your page does NOT have an element with ID of `table-meals` on it as rendered

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `#table-meals` and `.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal` are two different divs; each one corresponds to a purchase choice; if the user chooses *individual*, the `#table-meals` div remains hidden while `.product-addon-please-choose-your-meal` appears; if *Table of 10* if chosen, then vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is not without a significant number of other challenges which may be having a negative impact however, getting past that to specifically address your question.

Your radio inputs on the linked page are this:

```
<div class=" product-addon product-addon-please-choose-your-meal">
    <h3 class="addon-name">Please choose your meal:</h3>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1-0">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="1" /> 1 </label>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1-1">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="2" /> 2 </label>
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1-2">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" class="addon addon-radio" name="addon-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1[]" data-raw-price="" data-price="" value="3" /> 3 </label>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

These have a set of characters that need special care to use the quotes around the name: specifically the square brackets.

You can use this to specify by name:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="addon-2628-please-choose-your-meal-1[]"]').prop('checked', false);
```

As an alternative you can specify by the classes in there:

```
$('input[type=radio].addon.addon-radio').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, this seemed to have worked. Another question: Is there a better way, or even a correct way, to return the `#table-meals select` (first `if` statement) box to the default option (*Select an Option...*)? Right now, `$('#table-meals select').val("Select an Option...");` works, but if you toggle between purchase choices, then the select box comes up blank instead of on the default option.

Comment: @vytfla - Using Chrome I view your page, right click page, select View pages source (CTRL-U same thing); get new source page, click CTRL-F (find) type in "table-meals" and I see NO match so I have no idea on your page here as that is NOT on that page...  As I indicated previously I see lots of complexity on your page that would not pass a code inspection in my review.

Answer (score 0):

i see two options, the first and a really simple way without additional plugins would be to set the prop of the radio-button.

```
$('input[name="radioButton"]').prop('checked', false);
```

The second option would be to create the forms with the plugin chosen from jQuery:
https://plugins.jquery.com/chosen/

This plugin is simple nice to handle better with the input, select and other types in the form.

Let me know if it works for you
best regards
Jan

Comment: Actually it seems to be working some times, which is really frustrating and confusing. I've also tried `$('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);`, which also works some times.